# Network Manager Icon Isn't In the Unity Panel

Tags: unity, networking, network-manager

I accidentally purged network-manager. Hopefully, I downloaded the debs required by network-manager and installed them. Now, the network-manager indicator is not in the Unity panel. Is there a fix? Thanks a lot.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64 bit.

By the way, I've already searched the interwebs and haven't found a fix.

Comment: Try `apt-get install network-manager-gnome`

Comment: @bain I already have 'network-manger-gnome' installed and is the latest version.